# How to obtain .prj files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I am just about done with my shapefile in QGIS, but I needed help saving my shapefile as a .prj file. (If that is possible). If not, how do I obtain the .prj file for my shapefile?

Please advise.

Answer (score 11):

**.prj** file is a non-mandatory file for group of files generally called as *Shapefile*. Mandatory files are: .shp, .shx and .dbf

Citing wikipedia:
**.prj** — projection format; the coordinate system and projection information, a plain text file describing the projection using well-known text format

In **QGIS** you can create .prj file through menu:

**Vector - Data Management Tools - Define Current Projection...**

If you choose projection for your file and click ok, it will create .prj file for your shapefile.