# Create prj-file for shapefile in QGIS 3?

Tags: shapefile, qgis-3, import, prj

When you load in QGIS a shapefile without a PRJ file, you can set the coordinate system, but no PRJ file is created.

This older question: [How to obtain .prj files in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214556/how-to-obtain-prj-files-in-qgis/214559)

has an answer saying menu `"Vector - Data Management Tools - Define Current Projection"` does it, but it is not present in recent versions. Any suggestion of how to do it?

Of course, I can do it manually, copying the PRJ file of some other shape, but probably there is a way of doing it from within QGIS menus.

Answer (score 6):

There is a tool named Define Shapefile Projection for that purpose in the processing toolbox. The toolbox has a pretty useful search option that finds also this tool with search term "prj".

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That must be the tool that was before under menu "Vector".
Jose'

Answer (score 3):

You have first to set the [CRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system) of your layer by right clicking your layer > "`Properties...`"
Then under "`Set source coordinate reference system`" select the CRS of your choice and hit [`OK`].

[image: set layer CRS]

Finally, you have to export your vector data to an [ESRI Shapefile](https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) (it can be a new one) by right clicking your layer > "`Export`" > "`Save Features As...`"

[image: export layer]

Then your layer `*.prj` file will be there, nearby your freshly exported data on the disk!

Comment: I have done this and the .prj still is not being created. Anything else I might be missing?